# How to detect planar surface like AREffect

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I want to develop an application like [AREffect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonymobile.androidapp.cameraaddon.areffect) (which can run on Sony device only). I tried this app and it did not like any other AR app. It can detect planar surface and draw 3Dobject onto that surface. As i know, just only AREffect can do this. 
Anyone know which SDK or libraries support detect planar surface? Thanks everyone!